# Why won't my program run?

Tags: java, eclipse

So the program I am trying to create is The Game of Craps and I was trying to see whether or not the program was repeating itself because I really don't know how to use recursive methods and the professor went over it a while ago. I want to see whether or not it's running properly but when I run this I 
get: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError   at java.util.Random.(Unknown Source)  at Main.rollDice(Main.java:25)  at Main.rollDice(Main.java:29) and the Main.java:29 repeats numerous times. I'm new to coding and my professor isn't the best. Please help this is due in 12 hours!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
static int die1 = 0, die2 = 0, dieSum = 0, balance = 0, bet = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random gen = new Random();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Craps!");
    System.out.println("Every round you will make a wager with dollars only.");
    System.out.println("The minimum wager is $10.");
    System.out.println("You can continue to play as long as you have enough money to cover the minimu wager.");
    System.out.println("You can cash out at the end of any round if you would like.");

    balance = gen.nextInt(1000)+50;
    System.out.println("Your starting balance is: $" + balance);
    int i = 0;
    if ((rollDice()<=2)||(i==5)) {
        System.out.println(rollDice());
        i = i++;
    }
}
public static int rollDice() {
    Random gen = new Random();
    die1 = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    die2 = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    dieSum = die1 + die2;
    return rollDice();
}
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to use recursion in this code? What is the point?

Comment: Don't these instructions mean to use recursion? Your program must implement and use calls to the following methods:

static int rollDice()
Simulates rolling a pair of dice; returns an integer in the range {2, ..., 12}
 
static boolean rollWithPoint(int point)
Simulates rolling the dice until either the player wins (true is returned) or loses (false is returned)

Comment: Sorry for all the edits and mistakes haha. I'm new to posting on this website so I keep making mistakes.

Comment: The problem is that in your code you don't handle the case "until either the player wins", just keep rolling instead. Recursive function (method) must have terminating condition, otherwise it would call itself infinitely. PC's RAM isn't infinite though

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to get the dice to roll and add together now though. Shouldn't this code do that?balance = gen.nextInt(1000)+50;
  System.out.println("Your starting balance is: $" + balance);
  int i = 0;
  if ((dieSum<=2)||(i<5)) {
   System.out.println(dieSum);
   i = i++;
  }
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rollDice` method recursively calls itself without condition.  This line returns the result of calling rollDice `return rollDice();`  Each recursive call gets added to the execution stack.  Once the stack is "out of space", the stack overflow exception is thrown.  I suspect you intend to return `dieSum` like such

```
public static int rollDice() {
    Random gen = new Random();
    die1 = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    die2 = gen.nextInt(6)+1;
    dieSum = die1 + die2;    
    return dieSum;
}
```

Comment: Okay I did that but the die still aren't producing numbers between 1-6 and I don't know why

Comment: `rollDice` adds two dice together.  You should expect values between 2 -12.  I ran a quick test calling it 1000 times.  All values were in the range expected.

Comment: Wait that's probably why the code that I typed in the comments up above doesn't work. Because I'm not calling the method but I don't really know how to do that

Comment: You still need to write the `rollWithPoint` method.  You don't need recursion for that.  A `while` loop will work.  Call that method from main.